# best way to remove default apps on xoom

Tags: uninstallation, motorola-xoom

What is the best way to completely remove the default apps that came with the xoom? Since android apps are self contain packages is it enough just to remove the application package on the device through adk?

Comment: The Xoom has a locked bootloader that will restore the system image if it notices a missing app, if I'm not mistaken, so I think there are extra considerations here.

Comment: Unlike on their phones, they made the Xoom's bootloader unlockable.

Comment: @Matthew: As Chris already noted, the bootloader on the Xoom is unlockable (via `fastboot`).

Comment: Ah, awesome. I've updated my answer on the other question, so I'll vote to close as well.

Comment: Question (which is possibly in the wrong place): Which apps? I was led to believe the xoom sported vanilla hpneycomb withput any motorolatweaking - certainly it lacks touchwiz...

Comment: @syntheticbrain US Xoom models are "Google Experience" vanilla Android devices, Xooms sold in other countries may look like vanilla Android, but officially aren't "Google Experience" and do have a small number of pre-bundled apps (off the top of my head I think there's a wifi printing app and a Citrix client, there may be others). This is also why US Xooms get updates pushed to them months before the other models (also conversely why international models had working SD slots months before the US ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little extra care (such as taking backups first in case you want to go back), if you have root, simply `rm`-ing the `.apk` in `/system/app` is sufficient to remove system apps. Take care though, as removing certain apps may cause the system or other apps to crash.